# почему этот код считается плохой практикой

Tags: c++

```
std::vector create() {
    std::vector<HeavyType> temp = {... 10 objects }; // супер тяжелые объекты

    return temp;
}
```

на практике д никогда не сталкивался с таким, вопрос был на собеседовании, и не могу

понять в чем тут рофл, добавлю что предположим HeavyType очень тяжеловесный тип данных

Comment: не инициализированная переменная

Comment: @eri, всё инициализировано. Возвращается пустой вектор. Определение типа не помешает.

Comment: Вы при возврате значения копируете вектор. Если в нем много данных - то это очень затратная операция. А если он хранит ещё объекты, которые сами аллоцируют память, то это получится очень долго.

Comment: Может речь про RVO и NRVO? https://habr.com/ru/company/vk/blog/666330/

Comment: В новом коде все тяжёлые объекты скопированы один или два раза. Без этого можно было бы обойтись.

Comment: Так как (N)RVO не обязателен, то надо вместо push_back делать emplace_back, а массив передавать как ссылку. Так вы избежите лишний копирований тяжёлых объектов.

Comment: кажется я понял в чем проблема, спасибо 
DmitryK, и  
Stanislav Volodarskiy

Comment: в общем я создаю вектор, и плюс при возврате его копирую, лишняя копия и аллокации туда сюда(как же меня задрали плюсы, на каждом шагу можно споткнутся)

Comment: Вот если бы там был простой тип, тогда оптимизация RVO/NRVO скорее всего бы убрала лишнюю операцию копирования в `return`. А когда в векторе "тяжелый" тип, то скорее всего она не сработает и будут делаться копии всех объектов, лежащих в векторе.

Comment: можно ссылку на какой-нибудь достоверный источник, почему на RVO влияет тяжесть типа, лежащего в контейнере?

Comment: @DmitryK, ошибся, я полагаю. Вектора оптимизируются независимо от типа элемента.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Да, пожалуй я ошибся. Объекты внутри вектора не должны влиять на RVO самого вектора. Тогда вопрос относится не к возврату значения, а методу инициализации вектора.

Comment: Не понял, почему вы поменяли код в вопросе? Что у вас было на самом деле?

Comment: Код в вопросе изменен принципиально!

Comment: HolyBlackCat
 в общем создаетс вектор, неважно как, главное что тяжеловесный в теле функции, и потом return , я такое в проде не встречал, и очень удивился на собеседовании

Comment: Пожалуйста начинайте сообщения с `@username`, иначе мне не приходят уведомления.

Comment: Если дело не в `{...}`, то непонятно, почему вы удовлетворились моим ответом, в котором речь только про `{...}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что `std::initializer_list` (параметр конструктора вектора) сделан через одно место. Он хранит константные элементы, поэтому они будут копироваться, а не перемещаться.

А вот в `return temp;` все хорошо. Там либо одно перемещение вектора (не элементов), либо, что более вероятно, вообще ничего (если сработает NRVO).

---

Обратите внимание, это действует только на `std::initializer_list`, а **не** на любые списки в фигурных скобках.

Comment: [Возможно вам будет интересно](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53837373).

Answer (score 0):

В худшем случае все тяжёлые объекты копируются два раза: один при `push_back`, второй раз при возврате вектора из функции. Второе копирование может быть оптимизировано ([NRVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)), первое надо убирать меняя `push_back` на `emplace_back`.

Но, даже если NRVO не сработает, компилятор использует перемещающих конструктор, который есть у всех векторов. Этот конструктор не будет копировать сами тяжёлые объекты, только заголовок вектора - несколько байт.

На всякий случай дизайн без лишних копий:

```
void fill(std::vector<HeavyType> &a) {
    a.clear();
    a.reserve(1000000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
        a.emplace_back()
    } 
}
```

Comment: thx, не, прикол в том что именно в return, я в общем понял что при возврате копируется значение, кекв

Comment: это дизайн без лишних копий зато с вероятными лишними аллокациями. `reserve` было бы неплохо сделать

Comment: @BeardedBeaver, поправил.